# JavaScript PHP Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to make a DropDown Menu, where someone can Choose an option out of several options. Ans depending on this Value the other Dropdown menu should be updated with values out a Database.

Like

Option 1: kind of sport

Option 2: Time

Option 3: Place

.
.
.

// EDIT adding actual option.

```
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM kurs';
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);


    echo
    "<table border = 1>
                        <tr align = 'middle'>  
                            <td> <select>";
    while ($zeile = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option>" . $zeile['name'] . "</option>";
    }
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    echo
    "</td><td> <select>";
    while ($zeile = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option>" . $zeile['day'] . "</option>";
    }
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

and if someone update choose one option out of 'day', the other option 'name' should change depending on the 'day' and vice versa.

I know how to get the information out of my SQL Database but i don't know how to make the Select Area dynamic. I'm not allowed to use JQuery.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: "I'm not allowed to use jQuery". That sounds like homework. That aside, some important questions: (1) what do you mean by "dropdown menu should be updated"? By what trigger(s) and/or event(s)? (2) What is the relationship between the first and the other menus? If there is no code, it is extremely difficult to help.

Comment: It's not any homework, we just never had jquery at the lecture and we try to leanr php and javascript on our own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary: Use a `<select onchange...` event, XMLHttpRequest, and two PHP scripts.

To simplify the discussion, let's forget about Sport. The user first chooses a race date and then chooses an entrant name.  Initially, the date dropdown shows all the dates, and the name dropdown is blank. After selecting a date, the name dropdown is populated with all the names for that date.

And suppose the database is so large that you don't want to send all the data to the browser in one go. You only want to send the names after the user has chosen a date.

This is classic AJAX.  If you don't use jQuery (or another Javascript library), then you need to roll-your-own by using XMLHttpRequest (see http://www.w3schools.com/ajax ).  That's what jQuery does.

Now, to examine your code. `'SELECT * FROM kurs'` is going to give you all the records in the database. If you have 1000 records, your Date dropdown will have 1000 options! You might want:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT [day] FROM kurs ORDER BY [day]
```

If you want the Date dropdown to feed names into the Name dropdown as soon as the user chooses a date, without the need to click a Submit button, then do this:

```
    $optionlist = '<option value="">--Choose Race Date--</option>';
    while ($zeile = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $optionlist .= '<option>' . $zeile['day'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo "
      <table border='1'><tr>
        <td><select onchange='datechange(this)'>$optionlist</select></td>
        <td id='tdSelectName'><select disabled></select></td>
      </tr></table>";
```

The `--Choose Race Date--` option is there so that if the user happens to want the first date then there will still be an `onchange()` event.

Your Javascript will need:

```
    function datechange(sel) {
      raceDate = sel.value;
      if ( raceDate ) { 
        var myRequest = ...
        // your synchronous XMLHttpRequest code goes here
        document.getElementById("tdSelectName") = myRequest.responseText;
      }
    }
```

To see a fancier version of this in action, look at http://www.mostbryte.com/where_to_buy